# How do I go about this so that raw_visits_sum calculates the sum of all values for any date_range_start time?

Tags: sql

Essentially, I want this to only produce 1 row with the total raw visits for all any date range in April for that specific naics code

```
    select naics_code,
           date_range_start,
           sum(cast(raw_visit_counts as INT)) as raw_visits_sum
    from sg_monthly_foottraffic3
    where date_range_start like '2020-04%' and naics_code = '722515' 
    group by naics_code, date_range_start
```

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxkI7.png)

Comment: Please update your post with the text of your SQL, not screenshots.

Comment: @FoggyDay fixed

Answer (score 0):

You're grouping by "date_range_start" (apparently a text string, not a "date" type), and you've got 8 different "date_range_start" values ... so you get 8 rows.  As simple as that :)

POTENTIAL SOLUTION:

```
select naics_code,
       '2020-04%' as date_range_start,
       sum(cast(raw_visit_counts as INT)) as raw_visits_sum
from sg_monthly_foottraffic3
where date_range_start like '2020-04%' and naics_code = '722515' 
group by naics_code
```

Or, since you're only ever going to have one row:

```
select naics_code,
       '2020-04%' as date_range_start,
       sum(cast(raw_visit_counts as INT)) as raw_visits_sum
from sg_monthly_foottraffic3
where date_range_start like '2020-04%' and naics_code = '722515'
```

Or even:

```
select sum(cast(raw_visit_counts as INT)) as raw_visits_sum
from sg_monthly_foottraffic3
where date_range_start like '2020-04%' and naics_code = '722515'
```